# Django form, handle multiple entities creation

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want to do something that looks like what we can see in this image I made:

[image: Image describing the issue I want to solve]

Basically, I have two entities: `Project` and `Feature`.
Each project has a many-to-many relation to some features.

When I create a project, I want to be able to add as many features as I want, and I want to do it in one time (just one form).

So, what is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Inline model formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) are what you want.

Comment: Thank you <3 That's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this as your `models.py`

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project = models.Charfield(max_length=100)

class Feature(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=100)
    project = models.ManyToManyField(Project, blank = True)
```

`forms.py`:

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
```

Rough code snippets for `views.py`:

```
def project(request):
    ModelForm = inlineformset_factory(Project, Feature)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectForm(request.POST)
        project = Project.objects.get(pk=request.pk)
        formset = ModelForm(instance=project)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('')
    else:
        form = ProjectForm()
        formset = ModelForm()    
        return render_to_response('project.html', {'form':
form, 'formset': formset})
```